# Proof of Group Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, proof-verification

Prove that $\sigma\tau = \sigma\mu$ and $\tau\sigma = \mu\sigma$ in $S_n$, then $\tau = \mu$.

Workings:

Proof:

Since $\sigma\tau = \sigma\mu$

Then for $\tau$

$\tau = e\tau$

$\tau = (\sigma^{-1}\sigma)\tau$

$\tau = \sigma^{-1}(\sigma\tau)$

$\tau = \sigma^{-1}(\sigma\mu)$

$\tau = (\sigma^{-1}\sigma)\mu$

$\tau = e\mu$

$\tau = \mu$

Since $\tau\sigma = \mu\sigma$

Then for $\tau$

$\tau = \tau e$

$\tau = \tau(\sigma\sigma^{-1})$

$\tau = (\tau\sigma)\sigma^{-1}$

$\tau = (\mu\sigma)\sigma^{-1}$

$\tau = \mu(\sigma\sigma^{-1})$

$\tau = \mu e$

$\tau = \mu$

Therefore $ \tau = \mu$

I'm wondering if this correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those proofs look correct. It is more common to take the given equation and multiply both sides, either on the left or on the right, by $\sigma^{-1}$. But your proofs are equivalent to that method.

The problem seems to be badly stated, since only one of the two hypotheses is needed to get the conclusion, not both of them. Are you sure there was the word "and" between the two hypotheses rather than the word "or"?

Comment: No it said "and". Very strange. Thanks for the help.